# add a pdf document to every other page of an existing pdf document?

Tags: pdf, insert, edit, acrobat

It is seriously boggling my mind how hard this seems to be. I have tried 5 PDF applications now. I can't afford acrobat pro, but I'm sure it has the capability. I'm looking for the fastest/most simple way to do this. simply put: put a copy of pdf document "foo" after every page in pdf document "moo."

Use example: 
I have to inspect 3 vehicles. They all have order tickets and I have a personal checklist I use for each inspection. The order ticket is a single 3 page pdf. The checklist is a separate one page pdf.

I need to go from this:

1. volkswagon golf order ticket
2. honda civic order ticket
3. subaru impreza order ticket
4. (separate "checklist" page)

To this:

1. volkswagon golf order ticket
2. checklist
3. honda civic order ticket
4. checklist
5. subaru impreza order ticket
6. checklist

Comment: I found a solution. using PDF Toolkit (PDFTK). It goes a little something like this: 



`pdftk A=OrderTickets.pdf B=Checklist.pdf cat A1-1 B1-1 A2-2 B1-1 A3-3 B1-1 output properlyCombined.pdf`

pdftk can be found here: http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/  

I still have to punch in each number, but it works. I'm sure there's a faster solution out there.

Answer (score 1):

if your checklist-pdf file has the same fixed content, you can use this approach to avoid to do too many things manually

this is a script I wrote some time ago in linux that automatizes the process, only needing you digit the filename of pdf file you want be mixed with checklist pdf page

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#
echo "Enter file name"
read filename
pages="`pdftk $filename dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | cut -d : -f2`"
numpages=`for ((a=1; a <= $pages; a++)); do echo -n "A$a B1 "; done`
pdftk A=$filename B=checklist.pdf cat $numpages output $filename-alternated.pdf
exit 0
```

where **checklist.pdf** need to be present in directory you launch script

result **for a pdf file 16 pages originally long** *interleaved with checklist.pdf single page*:
[image: alternated pages]

you can also modify the script to make it usable in loop and add in one time, the same checklist pdf page to multiple documents (in alternate mode) in this way

**for f in *.pdf; do `script $f`; done**

---

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#
filename=$1
pages="`pdftk $filename dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | cut -d : -f2`"
numpages=`for ((a=1; a <= $pages; a++)); do echo -n "A$a B1 "; done`
pdftk A=$filename B=checklist.pdf cat $numpages output $filename-alternated.pdf
exit 0
```

in order to ad not a checklist pdf page to checklist.pdf page itself, you can put **checklist.pdf** outside working directory of script (for instance in **/tmp**)

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#
filename=$1
pages="`pdftk $filename dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | cut -d : -f2`"
numpages=`for ((a=1; a <= $pages; a++)); do echo -n "A$a B1 "; done`
pdftk A=$filename B=/tmp/checklist.pdf cat $numpages output $filename-alternated.pdf
exit 0
```